# Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.TableTools is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, datatables-1.10

I using DataTable.js. I want to add a button on my table. I am using Knockout.Js with TableTools 2.2.4 and DataTables 1.10.7.

Could some one please help me with the problem?

Sample Code is added for your reference.

```
getAppoiintmentData: function () {
    var self = this;
    showLoadingImage();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: "",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            noty({ text: "Failed to load Appointment data.", timeout: 5000, type: NOTY_MSG_TYPE.error });
            hideLoadingImage();
            // do something about the error
        },
        success: function (response) {
            self._extractAppointment(response.ReturnData);
            ko.applyBindings(MANAGE_APPOINTMENT_VIEW);
           var table =  $("#appoinmentListdatatable").DataTable({ responsive: true });
            $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table, {
                "buttons": [
                    "copy",
                    "csv",
                    "xls",
                    "pdf",
                    { "type": "print", "buttonText": "Print me!" }
                ]
            });
            hideLoadingImage();
        }
    });
}
$(function () {  MANAGE_APPOINTMENT_VIEW.getAppoiintmentData(); });
```

HTML Code:

```html
<div class="block full">
    <div class="block-title">
        <h2>Appointments</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive ">
        <table id="appoinmentListdatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-vcenter">
            <thead>
                <tr class="th">
                    <th width="5%"><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: makeAllCheckUnCheck($element.checked)" /> </th>
                    <th width="16%">Patient Name</th>
                    <th width="16%">Mobile No.</th>
                    <th width="16%">Appointment Date</th>
                    <th width="16%">Appointment Time</th>
                    <th>Reason</th>
                    <th width="8%">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- ko foreach: appoinmentList() -->
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked()"/></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Mobile"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: AppointmentDateText()"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: AppointmentTime"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Reason"></td>
                    <td style="text-align:center">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" data-bind="click: $parent.openPopUp" data-toggle="tooltip" title="View More" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                        <button class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-xs btn-danger" data-bind="click: $parent.confirmCancelAppointmentConfirm"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you referring `TableTools.js` do check it link here https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js .

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Comment: Yes I am refering to the TableTools.js. I am using it with Knockout.js. I am trying to get the buttons on the table which is populated using Knockout observable array values.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, check whether you are using multiple `Jquery` reference in your application. Perhaps you have not noticed the one referred from bundle. If referred multiple times, remove one. It will resolve your problem.